# ten green bottles programme python

Tags: python

I am writing a program in Python that prints the ten green bottles program based on how many bottles the user inputs. This is what I have so far.

```
x=input("How many bottles to start with?\n")                                                    
while x > 0:                                                    
  if(x==1):                                                 
    print (str(x) + " "+"green bottle, hanging on the wall")                                                    
    print (str(x) + " "+ "green bottle hanging on the wall")                                                    
    print ("and if one green bottle, should accidentally falls")                                                    
    x = x - 1                                                   
    print("there'd be no green bottle hanging on the wall")                                                 
    print("\n")                                                 
  elif(x==2):                                                   
    print (str(x) + " "+"green bottles, hanging on the wall")                                                   
    print (str(x) + " "+ "green bottles hanging on the wall")                                                   
    print ("and if one green bottle should accidentally fall")                                                  
    x = x - 1                                                   
    print ("there'd be "  + str (x)  + " green bottle, hanging on the wall")                                                    
    print("\n")                                                 
  else:                                                 
    print (str(x) + " "+"green bottles, hanging on the wall")                                                   
    print (str(x) + " "+ "green bottles hanging on the wall")                                                   
    print ("and if one green bottle should accidentally falls")                                                 
    x = x - 1                                                   
    print ("there'd be "  + str (x)  + " green bottles, hanging on the wall")                                                   
    print("\n")
```

Problem 1: I also need to change the '1' into a 'one'. I was thinking of writing a function as I only need to change 1 to 10. I  Please advise on how I can do that.

Comment: The [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) advises you how to write a function.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1**
This can be simply done with an if statement. Since you mentioned you need only 1 to 10, the statement should look like this

```py
x = int(input("How many bottles to start with? "))
if (x > 10 or x < 1):
    print(f"Can't start with {x} bottles. Pick a number between 1 and 10.")
    exit()
```

**Problem 2**
That can be done with a dictionary.

```py
map_to_str = {
    0: "NO",
    1: "ONE",
    2: "TWO",
    3: "THREE",
    4: "FOUR",
    5: "FIVE",
    6: "SIX",
    7: "SEVEN",
    8: "EIGHT",
    9: "NINE",
    10: "TEN"
}
```

Another problem with your code is that a lot of code is unnecessarily repeated. First, I would use a for loop. I would also write a function that returns number of bottles as string.

```py
def bottles_to_str(num_of_bottles):
    return f"{map_to_str[num_of_bottles]} green bottle" + "s"*(num_of_bottles!=1)
```

This function takes number as argument and converts it to string using a dictionary. It also checks if number of bottles is not equal to 1 (False can also be interpreted as 0 and True as 1). If number of bottles is not 1, it evaluates as `"s"*1` which is `'s'`, else it evaluates as `"s"*0` which is empty string `''`.

Main loop will look like this

```py
for i in range(x, 0, -1):
    print(f"{bottles_to_str(i)} hanging on the wall,")
    print(f"{bottles_to_str(i)} hanging on the wall,")
    print(f"And if one green bottle should accidentally fall,")
    print(f"There'll be {bottles_to_str(i-1)} hanging on the wall\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert numbers to their respective English words, it is advisable to use a dictionary:

```
x = int(input("How many bottles to start with?\n")) # Convert the input to an int
int_to_str = {
1: "one",
2: "two",
...
10: "ten"
}
print ("there'd be "  + int_to_str[x] + " green bottles, hanging on the wall")
```

Comment: just a side note, python input is by default string, index by int(x) might be needed

Comment: Of course. I convert numerical inputs to float or int by habit so I missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
toAlpha = {0 : "no",
           1 : "one",
           2 : "two",
           3 : "three",
           4 : "four",
           5 : "five",}  # And so on..

def bottleORbottles(x):
    if x > 1:
        return "bottles"
    return "bottle"

x=input("How many bottles to start with?\n")
if x == 0 :
    print("WE DONT HAVE ANY BOTTLES..")
    
while x > 0:
    print((toAlpha[x] + " green " + bottleORbottles(x) + " , hanging on the wall \n") *2)
    print ("and if one green bottle, should accidentally fall")
    x = x - 1
    print("there'd be " + toAlpha[x] + " green  " + bottleORbottles(x) + " hanging on the wall \n")
```

Look how redundancy can be removed by using small functions..

Answer (score 0):

To handle this I would write a dictionary with integers as the key and value of written number.

```
a_python_dictionary = {'key_some_name1' : 'value_some_value1',
                       'key_some_name2' : 'value_some_value2'}

Example:
number_dict = {0:'zero', 1:'one', 2:'two',
                     ...etc...,
               8:'eight', 9:'nine', 10:'ten'}
```

Next, write the function that'll use the dictionary, with f-strings (a type of string formatting).

```
def greenbottles(info=number_dict):
    user_input = input("Please enter a whole number.\n")
    try:
        user_input = int(user_input)
        while user_input > 0:
            if user_input >= 2:
                print(f"{(info[user_input]).capitalize()} your plural sentence")
                user_input -= 1
            else:
                print(f"{(info[user_input]).capitalize()} your singular sentence")
                user_input -= 1
        print("There are no more bottles.")
    except:
        print("You did not enter a number.")
```

So, what is happening in this function is:

```
"""
Line 1.
    def greenbottles(info=number_dict):
        defines a function called 'greenbottles' and presets a keyword argument of
        'info' equal to premade dictionary variable called 'number_dict'
Line 2.
    user_input = input("Please enter a whole number.\n")
        makes a variable inside the function called 'user_input' and prompts the
        user to enter a number. Now, this make the variable a defaulted string.
Line 3.
    try:
        this command will attempt to run thru the next lines of code indented under
        'try:'. If it returns an error, it will pass to the exception line 'except:'
Line 4:
    user_input = int(user_input)
        takes the 'user_input' variable and converts the data type to 'int' an integer
Line 5:
    while user_input > 0:
        starts a 'while loop', meaning while condition is true, do this.. the
        conditional is 'user_input' greater than '0'?
Line 6:
    if user_input >= 2:
        conditional inside the while, is 'user_input' greater than or equal to '2'
Line 7:
    print(f"{(info[user_input]).capitalize()} blah plural")
        if lines 5 & 6 result in True, print to the screen, this f-string.
        the f-string will format logic result inside '{}' to a string,
        with the rest of the string.
        Python uses a first in, first out approach.
          if the variable 'user_input' equals integer 5 
          ...a step by step break down of the line...
            print(f"{(info[user_input]).capitalize()} plural sentence")
                    ~turns into~
            print(f"{(info[5]).capitalize()} your plural sentence")
                    ~turns into~
            print(f"{('five').capitalize()} your plural sentence")
                    ~turns into~
            print(f"{'Five'} your plural sentence")
                    ~turns into~
            print("Five your plural sentence")
Line 8:
    user_input -= 1
        take value of variable and make it equal to 1 less than original value
Line 9:
    else:
        when Line 6 'if' conditional is not true, do this
Line 10:
    print(f"{(info[user_input]).capitalize()} your singular sentence")
        if Line 5 results in True, but Line 6 results in False 
        print to the screen, this f-string.
        the f-string will format logic result inside '{}' to a string,
        with the rest of the string.
        Python uses a first in, first out approach.
          the variable 'user_input' will only equal integer 1 
          ...a step by step break down of the line...
            print(f"{(info[user_input]).capitalize()} your singular sentence")
                    ~turns into~
            print(f"{(info[1]).capitalize()} your singular sentence")
                    ~turns into~
            print(f"{('one').capitalize()} your singular sentence")
                    ~turns into~
            print(f"{'One'} your singular sentence")
                    ~turns into~
            print("One your singular sentence")
Line 11:
    user_input -= 1
        take value of variable and make it equal to 1 less than original value
Line 12:
    print("There are no more bottles.")
        when Line 5 returns false, it ends while loop and print to the screen,
        'There are no more bottles.'
Line 13:
    except:
        if for any reason Lines 4 thru 12 return a error, do this...
        otherwise skip
Line 14:
    print("You did not enter a number.")
        most likely cause, is user didn't enter a number, print that message to
        screen.
"""
# Bonus
# using triple quotation marks, single or double: '''some text''' """some text"""
# are great ways of making multi-line strings, you can even use formatting
f'''some text {1+1} 
some more text'''
f"""some text {2+1} 
some more text {1+1}"""
# so, instead of using multi 'print' statements, use one...
print(f"""Here's a mulit-line
{'f-string'.capitalize()} with
some formating {'of'.upper()}
{'things '*3},
as a {'EXAMPLE'.lower()}.
""")
```

I hope this helps you, and your understanding of python.   :D